# ERROR: cannot launch node of type [darknet_ros/darknet_ros]:

Tags: ros, mavlink

dishita@dishita-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws/src/darknet_ros$ roslaunch darknet_ros darknet_ros.launch
... logging to /home/dishita/.ros/log/a54fc4ec-3828-11ed-8e10-2d44a183ac97/roslaunch-dishita-VirtualBox-7714.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://dishita-VirtualBox:37933/

## SUMMARY

PARAMETERS

- /darknet_ros/actions/camera_reading/name: /darknet_ros/chec...
- /darknet_ros/config_path: /home/dishita/cat...
- /darknet_ros/image_view/enable_console_output: True
- /darknet_ros/image_view/enable_opencv: True
- /darknet_ros/image_view/wait_key_delay: 1
- /darknet_ros/publishers/bounding_boxes/latch: False
- /darknet_ros/publishers/bounding_boxes/queue_size: 1
- /darknet_ros/publishers/bounding_boxes/topic: /darknet_ros/boun...
- /darknet_ros/publishers/detection_image/latch: True
- /darknet_ros/publishers/detection_image/queue_size: 1
- /darknet_ros/publishers/detection_image/topic: /darknet_ros/dete...
- /darknet_ros/publishers/object_detector/latch: False
- /darknet_ros/publishers/object_detector/queue_size: 1
- /darknet_ros/publishers/object_detector/topic: /darknet_ros/foun...
- /darknet_ros/subscribers/camera_reading/queue_size: 1
- /darknet_ros/subscribers/camera_reading/topic: /webcam/image_raw
- /darknet_ros/weights_path: /home/dishita/cat...
- /darknet_ros/yolo_model/config_file/name: yolov2-tiny.cfg
- /darknet_ros/yolo_model/detection_classes/names: ['person', 'bicyc...
- /darknet_ros/yolo_model/threshold/value: 0.3
- /darknet_ros/yolo_model/weight_file/name: yolov2-tiny.weights
- /rosdistro: noetic
- /rosversion: 1.15.14

NODES
/
darknet_ros (darknet_ros/darknet_ros)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [7722]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to a54fc4ec-3828-11ed-8e10-2d44a183ac97
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [7732]
started core service [/rosout]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [darknet_ros/darknet_ros]: Cannot locate node of type [darknet_ros] in package [darknet_ros]. Make sure file exists in package path and permission is set to executable (chmod +x)

Ive sourced the bash file and made the file executible using chmod +x ~/catkin_ws/src/darknet_ros

I am still getting this error, help me out.

Comment: Did it actually build correctly?

Comment: yeah, it build correctly,

Answer (score 0):

You have to build the darknet_ros repo again.
Use:

```
catkin build darknet_ros
```

also source the file again.

Answer (score 0):

`chmod +x ~/catkin_ws/src/darknet_ros` is not enough to make the ROS node file executable.
You have to locate the source file of the node, which probably is `darknet_ros/ros/ yolo_object_detector_node.cpp`, and make this file executable.